# Bug in writing Excel data to Dictionary in Python with OpenPyXL

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, dictionary

Sorry to hit you with a bunch of esoteric code, but I have come across a bug which I have no idea how to fix.

Basically, I want to read individual cells in spreadsheet columns and write their data to a corresponding dictionary (called dataSet).

I created a function to do this:

```
def loopCol(col, start_offset, write_list):
'''
Loop through 1 column (col) until it ends. Skip header by start_offset.
Write data to list within DataSet dict
'''
from openpyxl.utils import column_index_from_string

# Create list and capture str of its name
list_string = str(write_list)
print(list_string)
if list_string not in dataSet:
    raise KeyError('List name not within DataSet Keys')
write_list = []

# Loop through column, capturing each cell's value
# Use start_offset to skip header cells
for i in range(column_index_from_string(col) + start_offset,
               sheet.max_row + 1):
    listItem = sheet[col + str(i)].value
    print(listItem)
    if listItem != None:
        if isinstance(listItem, datetime.datetime):
            listItem = listItem.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
            write_list.append(listItem)
        else:               
            write_list.append(listItem)

# Write data to dataSet
for list_index in write_list:
    dataSet[list_string] = [list_index for list_index in write_list]

loopCol('A', 0, 'dates')
loopCol('B', 0, 'ph')
loopCol('C', 0, 'water_level')
loopCol('D', 0, 'salinity')
loopCol('E', 1, 'conductivity')
loopCol('F', 0, 'tds')
```

So in theory, this should go through all the cells in one column, and if there's some value in them, write that value to its corresponding place in this dictionary:

```
dataSet = {
'dates': [],
'ph': [],
'water_level': [],
'salinity': [],
'conductivity': [],
'tds': []
}
```

However, there's a problem. When all is said and done the dictionary looks like:

```
{'ph': [3.4, 2.1, 7], 'salinity': [2.2, 1.2], 'conductivity': [5.3], 'water_level': ['2m', '3m', '1m'], 'tds': [], 'dates': ['Date', '21/01/2016', '28/01/2012', '06/03/2012']}
```

Now I know there's exactly 3 cells with values in each column. However some aren't making it into the dictionary. 'salinity' only gets 2 values, 'conductivity' only gets one and 'tds' is empty. These do happen to be the last entries in the dataSet dict, so maybe that's part of the reason. But I just can't figure out where the bug in the logic is.

[image: Here's a screen of the file for context]

Can someone please help? I really want to impress my boss ;) (I don't work in IT, so any computer wizardry that makes peoples life easier is met with wonder and awe).

If I didn't do well enough to explain exactly what the code is doing let me know and I'll try to clarify.

Comment: Please, add screenshot of excel file example for good imagination

Comment: Good idea. It's up now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
def colValues(sheet, keys, offsets=None):
    if offsets is None or not len(offsets):
        # Set offsets default to 0
        offsets = {k: 0 for k in keys}
    if len(offsets) != len(keys):
        # If offsets given, fail if length mismatch
        raise AttributeError()

    res = {}
    for column in sheet.columns:
        # Store current column header field (i.e. its name)
        ch = column[0].value
        if ch not in keys:
            # Fail early: No need for any tests if this column's data
            # is not desired in result set.
            continue
        # Append all row values to the result dict with respect to the
        # given column offset. Note: Lowest possible row index is 1,
        # because here we assume that header fields are present.
        res[ch] = [c.value for c in column[offsets[keys.index(ch)] + 1:]]
    return res

if __name__ == '__main__':
    xlsx = 'test.xlsx'
    ws = load_workbook(xlsx)['Sheet1']

    ds = colValues(ws, ['foo', 'bar'], [0, 1])
    print(ds)
```

For my small test, this yields the correct number of items per column. Note, that the key `'bar'` has one item less here, because its offset is higher in the above function call.

```
{u'foo': [2.3, 3.5, 5.6, 7.9], u'bar': [6.2, 3.6, 9L]}
```

In addition, the code is way lighter.

Comment: It works great and you're right, it's way cleaner and more robust than what I wrote. Thanks so much for the help!